# How to find a source IP adress in a WCF trace file using (Microsoft Service Trace Viewer)?

Tags: wcf, trace

I have a WCF web service with tracing enabled (following these guidelines http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702726.aspx).
The problem is that I cannot find the source IP (incomming client request) address anywhere in the trace file.
Also documentation on this topic is pretty vague, so if you can provide any links to some nice resources I'd be gratefull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logging client IP address is probably not on by default as it is a [privacy concern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480490.aspx).

This [links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733053.aspx) tells about some logging switches that allows you to trace things like the client IP address and when they are logged. I haven't set these flags before so can't tell you if it will work. But have a go.

Comment: I tried and still no client IP is being logged. Anyway, thanks for reply.

Comment: Strangely it started working fine :D
In Microsoft Service Trace Viewer you need to look for remote IP in "Listen at... " activity, "Connection information." description and there either on "Formatted" tab in "General Properties" there's "Remote Endpoint" value or in "XML" tab look for E2ETraceEvent/ApplicationData/TraceData/DataItem/TraceRecord/ExtendedData/RemoteEndpoint element.
Thanks for help Pratik.